# Can not connect to other VM on the same network from kubernetes pod

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I are currently running a Kubernetes cluster on GCP. The cluster has several pods. And I created a new VM in the same network. From Kubernetes pod can ping to the VM but can not connect via internal IP of VM. Please help me find solution for this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this issue. Create a firewall on GCP for VM to allow source from pod IP as `10.0.0.0/8`